SwiftUI + Sqlite 3 (stephencelis) - how to create sqlite3 order statement in variable?
I use SQLite.swift library and have a question regarding the order method.
Related to the SQLite.swift sort syntax, I would like to put the sort order in a variable, as I need different sort statements for my query in reference to a special conditions in the code.
Here is the syntax when the sort is supplied as a parameter to order, as shown in the documentation:
users.order(email.asc, name.asc)

Here is my first try to move it into a variable:
let orderStatement: ??? = email.asc, name.asc // <– the correct assignment is my problem 
users.order(orderStatement)

What is the correct syntax to achieve my goal?

From a quick look at their GitHub repo, it seems like let orderStatement = [email.asc, name.asc] should work.

SwiftUI has nothing to do with SQL that is just Swift as in the language

If you look at the Xcode “quick help” (⌥-⌘-3), it tells you that order expects an Array of Expressible:
func order(_ by: [any Expressible]) -> Table {…}

Or there is also a variadic rendition:
func order(_ by: any Expressible...) -> Table {…}


So, you can simply supply an array of any Expressible:
let sortBy: [any Expressible] = [name.asc, email.asc]
let query = users.order(sortBy)

Or, you can infer the type:
let sortBy = [name.asc, email.asc]
let query = users.order(sortBy)


Many thanks. That is the solution.
